# Git Clone not importing the data

Tags: git, github

Hi I am using below git command on linux server.

```
[root@servername git1]# git clone http://uname:pass@domainname/prj/DEV/rtw.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /var/dir/dir1/tmp/git1/rtw/.git/
```

After that it doesn't moves to next line, seems like hanged then print `fatal: HTTP request failed`.When i check the git1 directory it has .git folder, but not contains any code files. Any advice.

Thanks

Comment: Which linux version is on the server? Which Git version is on the server and on your client?

Comment: Is the folder rtw created on the same folder level, .git folder should be present in rtw directory and not git1

Comment: Can you access `http://uname:pass@domainname/prj/DEV/rtw.git` in your browser?

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 and git : git version 1.7.1. I updated my post after some time it gives error like fatal: HTTP request failed

Comment: Yes i can access, using virtual desktop i can access the url,even on that desktop clone is working like when click on desktop and using bash. But through back end its not working.

Comment: enter into your partially cloned folder and issue `git log`, and `git reset --hard HEAD`, and then `ls`, and show us the output

Comment: and one yet question: have you an access to `http://uname:pass@domainname` via ssh?

Comment: when i use `git log`, it shows me `fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'`